# Simplify function with a derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

This may be a very simple question: how can I substitute out a term involving a derivative in Mathematica?

I have the following derivative:

```
D[Wf, X] /. {z -> zbar, B[h] -> Bbar, x -> xbar, y -> ybar, X -> xbar,Y -> ybar}
```

...and it's solution in Mathematica:

[image]

Now whenever the following term appears anywhere in my Mathematica code, I would like to substitute in the variable 'bf':

[image]

i.e.:

```
bf = ef*(Derivative[1][B][ef xbar (1 - zbar) + em ybar zbar])/Bbar
```

In other words, the result of my derivative should be:

```
(1-zbar)bf
```

The 'Simplify' function should do this, I think, but the following doesn't seem to work:

[image]

Is this a simple mistake in syntax for 'Simplify'? Or perhaps I have misunderstood the scope of 'Simplify'?

Comment: What does `Wf` look like? A lot of times it is simpler to give `Derivative` a downvalue that does your replacement instead of trying to undo things after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

I've realised how to do it:

1. Set up a substitution rule:

```
mySubstitution = ef*(Derivative[1][B][ef xbar (1 - zbar) + em ybarzbar])/Bbar -> Bf
```

2. Find the derivative:

```
D[Wf, X] /. {z -> zbar, B[h] -> Bbar, x -> xbar, y -> ybar, X -> xbar,Y -> ybar}
```

3. Apply the substitution rule:

```
% /. MySubstitution
```